# How to make all new files in a directory executable

Tags: files, executable, chmod

I want a way by which whenever I create a new file in a particular directory, I want it to be executable by default.

Is this even possible, if so how?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580584/setting-default-permissions-for-newly-created-files-and-sub-directories-under-a/13906099#13906099

Comment: This is the easiest to read document regarding ACL (Access Control Lists) I could find: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

Answer (score 1):

You can change permission of a directory using the following command
chmod -R 700 directory

where -R ----> recursively apply permission all sub-directories and files under directory

Comment: By my understanding, this will mark all existing files as executable, but any new files written after running this will not be.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, how you create the file. If you want strict executable for the creator only, than use:

```
chmod 100 myfile
```

If you need read-write access as well:

```
chmod 700 myfile
```

A little help: http://www.meine-erste-homepage.com/chmod-generator.php

Automatic creation can be done wuth `install` (part of coreutils):

```
install -b -m 700 /dev/null myfile
```

Comment: That is not what he wants. He wants it automatic.

Comment: Ok, completed my answer.